# How to change vimtex highlight colors for matching delimiters?

Tags: vim

I've installed vimtex and have enabled highlighting of matching delimiters, but it's a bit painful to see the highlighted part. How can I change the highlight color?

[image: highlighted delimiters pic]

Comment: Have you tried disabling one plugin at a time to see if the problem goes away?

Comment: @L3viathan Just figured it out, it was vimtex plugin, but I still don't know how to change highlight color?

Comment: I think you should be able to disable it by setting `g:vimtex_motion_matchparen` to 0 in your `.vimrc`, but I don't know how to change the colors.

Comment: @L3viathan I realize disabling it might be the only option, might open up an issue on vimtex Github and see who's got a solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This can be changed using the `MatchParen` highlighting group, for example:

`:hi MatchParen ctermbg=5`